# Running Genymotion VM with GPS Enabled from Command Line

Tags: cmd, gps, command, genymotion

I am using unpaid version of Genymotion and want to run my GenyMotion device with GPS enable from command line. Please suggest me a way

Right now, i am using the following command which starts the virtual device.

*player --vm-name "DEVICE_NAME"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Genyshell:

```
genyshell -c "gps setstatus enabled"
```

You can find more information about Genyshell here: https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/Genymotion_Shell/Genymotion_Shell.htm

Remember, the "personal use" license of Genymotion is forbidden for commercial products.

Disclaimer: I'm part of the Genymotion team

Comment: Thanks. I am using genymotion for just evaluation purpose.

Comment: So you definitely should ask for a trial license. You will access all the business features to try the soft for real. Go to https://www.genymotion.com/contact/ send a message to the sales and tell you are coming from Eyal ;-)